# Convert array syntax for ArrrayList

Tags: java

If I have:

```
public static int[] leftHalf(int[] array) 
{
    int size1 = array.length / 2;
    int[] left = new int[size1];
    for (int i = 0; i < size1; i++) {
        left[i] = array[i];
    }
    return left;
}
```

Is this equivalent to

```
public static ArrayList<T> leftHalf(ArrayList<T> list) 
{
    int sizeLeft = list.size()/2;
    ArrayList<T> left = new ArrayList<T>(sizeLeft);
    for(int i=0; i<sizeLeft; i++)
    {
        left.add(list.get(i));
    }
    return left;
}
```

I think the add part is the tricky one since ArrayList has different properties with regards to things like size and capacity. Is the conversion correct?

Comment: Looks OK to me.  What happened when you tested it?

Comment: It's not *strictly* equivalent.  The `ArrayList` won't ever be a fixed, finite size, but you will give it the initial capacity of `sizeLeft`.  When it reaches a certain threshold of size, it will double its space.

Comment: @DavidWallace It's part of a merge sort algorithm which doesn't seem to be working properly. I'm converting it from an int array implementation i Googled up.

Comment: @Makoto Let's assume it won't have to double its capacity, will it behave exactly the same way as the first code?

Comment: Not really what I asked.

Comment: @DavidWallace well the whole code didn't work properly so I thought it had to do with the conversion of this method. Now it works, but it had nothing to do with the conversion itself. That asides I've gained some valuable knowledge.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Outside of the fact that you're passing in an `int[]`, and the `ArrayList` is bound to *any* object, the two methods are practically equivalent.

Although, the second form can be greatly simplified, as `ArrayList` has a convenient [copy constructor for collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList%28java.util.Collection%29).  You can also [take a sublist](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#subList%28int,%20int%29) of the passed-in list as well, making this a one-liner which accomplishes the same thing as the iteration piece.

```
public static <T> List<T> leftHalf(List<T> list) {
    return new ArrayList<T>(list.subList(0, list.size() / 2));
}
```

Comment: Your sublist suggestion is accurate but there is no overload of the ArrayList constructor that will create the sublist.

Comment: Erm...I don't follow you.  The constructor provided will accept the sublist as a valid argument.

Comment: @Makoto No `ArrayList` constructor takes the particular combination of arguments that you have in your code

Comment: Look again at the docs. 3 available constructors for ArrayList. Default constructor `ArrayList()`, `ArrayList(Collection<? extends E> c)`, and `ArrayList(int initialCapacity)` but not one that takes two params. So the answer you gave does not compile.

Comment: Oops.  Missed that bit.  Give me a mo and I'll fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Nearly. It's almost a generic version, I think you wanted

```
// Use the List interface(s).
public static <T> List<T> leftHalf(List<T> list) { // NOTE: generic type <T> after static, 
                                                   // but before List<T>
  int sizeLeft = list.size()/2;
  List<T> left = new ArrayList<T>(sizeLeft);
  for(int i = 0; i < sizeLeft; i++) {
    left.add(list.get(i));
  }
  return left;
}
```

Your `int[]` still isn't equivalent to `List<Integer>` or even `Integer[]` but they can have similar behavior. Especially since `ArrayList` is backed by an array, in which case you can explicitly return or accept the `ArrayList`.

Comment: What if I'm implementing this for a List<T> object but converting it to ArrayList<T> before converting it back to List<T>? Can I just do ArrayList<T> here because I'm just using strictly ArrayList<T>?

Comment: I'd add that it's possible that the OP may specifically *want* an `ArrayList` as the return value; it's not *always* appropriate to generify the implementation.

Comment: @user3511965 You certainly can use `ArrayList` if you prefer.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch How's public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> ArrayList<T> leftHalf(ArrayList<T> list) ? This is what I'm actually doing but the ArrayList<T> part I'm not too sure if this could create problems, not that I'm seeing any.

Comment: The closest thing to `T[]` you can get is `ArrayList<T>` in terms of behavior, I believe. The only problem that I can come up with is that `ArrayList` changes size, which a regular array won't do, but otherwise it's close enough.